# Does C have a concatenation operator?

Tags: c, verilog

[This Verilog tutorial](http://www.asic-world.com/verilog/verilog_one_day1.html#Introduction) (see the table at the end) suggests that `{ }` is a concatenation operator is C. I don't remember curly brackets as being an *operator* in C.

Is `{ }` a concatenation operator in C?

Comment: No, not really. `{}` form statements into a *block*.

Comment: Even C++ does not have that sort of thing - informing before you reach another such tutorial on C++ in future.

Comment: The `begin..end` and `fork..join` keywords form a block in Verilog.

Comment: If you're _looking_ for some sort of Verilog'esque concatenation in C ( well... C++), then the C++ library [System C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SystemC) can be used.  If you're in the Verilog design space, then using/learning System C could help you with a lot of the common hardware manipulations you need to do for a testbench or RTL simulation.  FYI, you might have to strip out the `main` symbol from the system C library to avoid invoking the simulation kernel.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, that's just nonsense. No idea what that's about.

Answer (score 3):

From the linked tutorial:

> To make life easier for us, **nearly all** operators (at least the ones in the list below) are exactly the same as their counterparts in the C programming language.

Emphasis mine.  The exceptions are `~&`, `~|`, `~^`, `^~`, and `{}`.

Adjacent string *literals* are automatically concatenated:

```
char *str = "This is the first half " 
            "and this is the second half";
```

Anything involving a `char` buffer, though, requires a library function like `strcat`:

```
char buf[SOME_SIZE];
...
strcat(buf, "This is the first half ");
strcat(buf, "and this is the second half");
```

There is also the preprocessor token pasting operator `##`, but the result must be a valid *preprocessor* token.

Comment: Well I find the **(at least the ones in the list below)** misleading.

Comment: Yeah.  Unfortunately, there's no QA for online tutorials.

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely not. The curly braces in C as C++, C# and others delimit a block of code. It's an error on their site. There is neither the possibility of operator overloading since we talk of 'pure, old fashioned C programming language'

Answer (score 1):

No, in pure C, the braces are not a concatenation operator.

Note that the table of operators on the Verilog page includes a number of other 'non-C, non-C++' operators:

```
~&    nand
|     or
~|    nor
^     xor
^~    xnor
~^    xnor
```

Where the operators are the same as in C, they have the same meaning as in C.  But there are operators in Verilog that are not in C (and, if that table is complete, operators in C that are not in Verilog).

Answer (score 1):

The only operator C has with `{ }` is the `( ){ }` operator which is the compound literal operator.

Answer (score 0):

Depends. Curly brackets are not an operator by definition in C, and they do not concatenate strings. But they group statements and introduce new blocks. Maybe this is what the author meant. But however, it is at least inaccurate if not wrong.

Answer (score -1):

## is a concatenation operator....